# Split string by every first space in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a string:

```
"AB C   D E   F"
```

I need to split it into an array so that it looks like:

```
[AB][C][ ][D][E][ ][F]
```

The most I can find online is splitting by " ", which gets rid of every space, and another way that only splits by the first space in the entire string.

Comment: What's the value to return for the three consecutive whitespaces?

Comment: Fixed, and respecified

Comment: I think you want (as the desired result) `["AB"," ", "C", " ", "D", " ", "F"]` or `[["AB"],[" "], ["C"], [" "], ["D"], [" "], ["F"]]`. What you have is not a valid Ruby object. Or, perhaps you wish to (cont.)

Comment: ...split on one or more spaces, keeping one space in the array returned when splitting on two or more spaces. It still requires clarification, however.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You do this by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe using `scan` would give you your expected output easier:

```
p str.scan(/[A-Z]+|\s{3}/)
# ["AB", "C", "   ", "D", "E", "   ", "F"]
```

As your input is only capitalized characters, `[A-Z]` would work, `/[a-z]/i` is for both cases.

Wondering why such an output:

```
p str.scan(/[A-Z]+|\s{3}/).map(&:split)
# [["AB"], ["C"], [], ["D"], ["E"], [], ["F"]]
```

Comment: Great answer :) got a hint from this answer "using a regex with split"

Comment: OK, that seemed to work, except I left out that the string would be like 
"AB C D   EF"
and needs to be split into 
[AB] [C] [D] [ ] [EF]

Comment: Add a `+` after `[a-z]`.

Comment: cooltop101, when you write `[AB], [C], [  ], [D], [E], [  ], [F]`, which is not a valid Ruby object,the reader must assume what you really mean. You say it's an array, so it should be enclosed in brackets. If you mean the first element to be the array `["AB"]` the string `"AB"` needs quotes. The two arrays `[  ]` each contain a space, so it's not clear if you mean an empty array, which is generally written without space, or an array containing a single space character (`[" "]`). I mention this to emphasize the importance of writing clear questions. You still need to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

split on spaces.

```
str="A B C  D E  F".split(/\s/)
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "", "D", "E", "", "F"]
```

or

```
str="A B C  D E  F".split(/\s|[a-z]/)
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "", "D", "E", "", "F"]
```

to prove that it works, split on spaces, join on space, and then split on spaces again. Control chars remain unaffected  :)

```
str="A B C  D E  F".split(/\s|[a-z]/).join(" ").split(/\s|[a-z]/)
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "", "D", "E", "", "F"]
```

Other variations/options to explore:

```
str="A B C  D E  F".split(/(\s)/)
#=> ["A", " ", "B", " ", "C", " ", "", " ", "D", " ", "E", " ", "", " ", "F"]

str="A B C  D E  F".split(//)
#=> ["A", " ", "B", " ", "C", " ", " ", "D", " ", "E", " ", " ", "F"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"AB C   D E   F".scan(/\S+|\s{2,}/)
#=> ["AB", "C", "   ", "D", "E", "   ", "F"]
```